# Which version of SDK does my pipeline use, if we have 2.2.0 in our classpath?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The latest version of beam-sdks-java-core is 2.3.0. However, if my pipeline code uses beam-sdks-java-core 2.2.0, then would my pipeline use 2.2.0 or 2.3.0 while running in Dataflow?

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline would be implemented using v2.2.0. The Apache Beam SDK is separate from Google Cloud Dataflow. You control which version of Beam you use. Dataflow simply executes the Beam pipeline. The Dataflow UI displays which version of Beam is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Take this answer as a complement to @Andrew's answer.

If you are using Maven, you can also specify the `beam-sdks-java-core` version in use in the `pom.xml` configuration file of your pipeline, as explained in the [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In order to specify the version you want to use, you can follow the guide on [Maven's version range specification](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html).

Also you can see the full list of available Maven dependencies in [this other link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#version-220), where as you can see, for Cloud Sataflow SDK jor Java 2.2.0, `org.apache.beam <--> beam-sdks-java-core <--> 2.2.0` is one of the available options.

If you are not using Maven, then in any case the Pipeline should use the dependency you have specified in your working directory, as it will be from there that it will take the required files to work with the SDK.